# $R$ a commutative ring, $I$, $J$ are comaximal ideals, and $M$ is an $R$-module, then $(I\cap J)M = IM\cap JM$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I am trying to prove the Chinese remainder theorem for modules, i.e. if $R$ commutative, $I,J$ comaximal ideals, and $M$ an $R$-module, then $M/IJM \simeq M/IM\times M/JM$. I have defined \begin{align*}
\varphi: M/IJM &\to M/IM \times M/JM\\
m+IJM &\to (m+IM, m+JM)
\end{align*}
I am trying to show that this map has a trivial kernel to prove injectivity. If $m\in  \ker(\varphi)$ we would have $m\in IM\cap JM$. I know that comaximality of $I$ and $J$ means that $I\cap J = IJ$. So I want to show that $m\in (I\cap J)M$ to show $m\in IJM$.

Thus, I want to show $IM\cap JM = (I\cap J)M$. I can show $(I\cap J)M \subseteq IM\cap JM$ pretty easily but I am having trouble showing $IM\cap JM\subseteq (I\cap J)M$. If $m\in IM\cap JM$, I know that (courtesy of Servaes in the comments) \begin{align*}
m &= \sum i_km_k\\
m &= \sum j_\ell m_\ell'
\end{align*}
for $i_k\in I, j_\ell\in J, m_k,m_\ell\in M$ and each sum is finite.  I want to show that each $i_k, j_\ell\in I\cap J$. We have that \begin{align*}
\sum (i_k-j_k) m_k &= 0
\end{align*}
where $i_k$ or $j_k$ could be $0$ depending on whether $m_\ell'$ corresponds with some $m_k$ or vice versa. If I could say $i_k = j_k$, I would get that $i_k,j_k\in I\cap J$ and be done. I am tempted to say this is the case since the sum adds up to $0$ and I feel like I can try to invoke some argument about $R$-linear independence here, but I am not too sure how to proceed with doing that.

Comment: Your last statement is false; if $m\in IM\cap JM$ then $m=\sum i_km_k'$ and $m=\sum j_lm_l''$, where the sums are finite.

Comment: I see, I will edit my post and approach and see what progress I can make

Comment: @Servaes I've edited my post and approach to account for the error I made.

Comment: Is $R$ unitary?

Comment: @user26857 Yes, $R$ is a commutative ring with multiplicative identity

Comment: Then write $1=a+b$ with $a\in I$ and $b\in J$. For $m\in IM\cap JM$ we have $m=am+bm$. But $am\in I(JM)$ and $bm\in J(IM)$

Comment: @user26857 This makes perfect sense, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The Chinese Remainder Theorem holds for modules indeed (and not just for two comaximal ideals, but for any finite number of pairwise comaximal ideals). See

- Keenan Kidwell's answer at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18959/chinese-remainder-theorem-for-rings-why-not-for-modules for a slick proof using tensor products, and
- [my *Witt#5c: The Chinese Remainder Theorem for Modules*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/witt5c.pdf) for a manual proof that I have written before I understood how to properly use tensor products for base change :)